# Como sumo la columna total dependiendo el numero de venta

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Lo que quiero hacer es que en cada venta me aparezca el total de ese numero de venta, abajo dejo mi codigo y una imagen para que me entiendan mejor, de ante mano gracias

```
<?php
    include "conectar.php";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Panel de Administración</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/estilo.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  href="./js/scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <img src="./imagenes/logo.png" id="logo">
        <a href="./carritodecompras.php" title="ver carrito de compras">
            <img src="./imagenes/carrito.png">
        </a>
    </header>
    <section>
    <nav class="menu2">
      <menu>
        <li><a href="./">Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="selected">Admin</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" >Agregar</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Salir</a></li>
      </menu>
    </nav>

    <center><h1>Últimas Compras</h1></center>
    <table border="1px" width="100%">   
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Clave</td>
            <td>Fecha de pedido</td>
            <td>Productos</td>
            <td>Precio</td>
            <td>Cantidad</td>
            <td>Cliente</td>
            <td>Total</td>
        </tr>   

        <?php
            $consulta=$Conexion->prepare("SELECT Id_pedido, Numeroventa, Fecha_pedido, Productos.Descripcion, Pedido.Precio, cantidad, Usuarios.NOMBRE, Total from Pedido JOIN Productos JOIN Usuarios WHERE Pedido.Id_producto=Productos.Id_producto AND Pedido.Id_usuario=Usuarios.Id_usuario");
            $consulta->execute();
            $resultado = $consulta->fetchALL();
            $numeroventa=0;
            foreach ($resultado as $f) {
                    if($numeroventa !=$f['Numeroventa']){
                        echo '<tr><td>Compra Número: '.$f['Numeroventa'].' </td></tr>';
                    }
                    $numeroventa=$f['Numeroventa'];
                    echo '<tr>
                        <td>'.$f['Id_pedido'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$f['Fecha_pedido'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$f['Descripcion'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$f['Precio'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$f['cantidad'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$f['NOMBRE'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$f['Total'].'</td>

                    </tr>';
            }
        ?>
    </table>
    </tbody>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Esta es la imagen de como esta actualmente mi tabla
[image: Imagen]

Como decia lo que quiero es que se sume por ejemplo la columna total de la compra numero 10 es decir daria un total de 408 asi en cada una y que al final me de tambien un total de todos los numero de compras

Comment: puedes crear una varible `$total =0;` fuera del bucle `foreach` y sumarle los valores ejemplo: `$total += $f['Precio'] * $f['cantidad'];`  o tambien `$total +=$f['Total'];`y luego imprimerlo al terminar el `foreach`

Comment: Con dos variables dentro del foreach, uno para sumar por cada producto y otro que acumule  $f['Total'] hasta que recorra todos los productos.

Comment: @Bryro no me los esta sumando que puedo hacer? solo me aparece el precio del primer producto que esta en se numero de venta, podrias mostrarme como hacerle con el codigo por favor

Answer (score 1):

aquí te dejo el código completo y explicado para resolver tú problema, si tienes alguna duda u inconveniente no dudes en comentarme.

Aunque el código no utilice exactamente los mismos valores que en el tuyo, la estructura está pensada para que los puedas añadir reemplazando $products por tu $resultado y luego ya ir declarando los valores que necesitas.

## Vista del código php completo

```
    <?php

// $products equivale a $resultado
$products = array( 0 => array('id' => '23332', 'num_venta' => 12, 'total' => 7), 
             1 => array('id' => '333', 'num_venta' => 23, 'total' => 16),
             2 => array('id' => '234', 'num_venta' => 23, 'total' => 14)
);

/*
    Esta variable se ha declarado para conocer que número de venta estamos 
    cargando.
    
    Si te fijas, he cargado el primer número de venta del primer producto,
    esto lo hago para que empiece el loop de productos con un pedido 
    seleccionado.
*/
$current_order = $products[0]['num_venta'];
// Esta variable almacena el precio total del número de venta actual.
$current_total_price = 0;
// Esta variable almacena el número total de productos del número de venta actual.
$current_total_products = 0;

/*
    Esta función pinta la fila de un producto. Además de esto, también
    actualiza el precio total que llevamos sumado en el pedido, y el
    total de productos que tiene el pedido.

    Declaro 'global' dentro de una función para poder manipular
    las variables que se encuentran fuera de esta, sino, las trata
    como unas variables nuevas creadas dentro de la propia función
    aunque se llamen igual.
*/
function setProductRow($order) {
    global $current_total_price;
    global $current_total_products;

    $current_total_price += $product['total'];
    $current_total_products += 1;

    echo '<tr>
        <td>'.$product['id'].'</td>
        <td>'.$product['total'].'</td>
    </tr>';
}

/*
    Esta función pinta la fila de los valores totales del pedido.

    Como puedes ver es bastante similar a la anterior función, no hay
    mucho misterio con esta una vez has entendido lo anterior.
*/
function setTotalsRow() {
    global $current_order;
    global $current_total_price;
    global $current_total_products;

    echo '<tr>
        <td>Compra número: '.$current_order.'</td>
        <td>Total precio: '.$current_total_price.'</td>
        <td>Total productos: '.$current_total_products.'</td>
    </tr>';

    $current_total_price = 0;
    $current_total_products = 0;
}

/*
    Y aquí está el loop que lo hace todo, como puedes ver estoy haciendo
    un foreach de los productos y saco la key que es el indice en el array
    del producto, y el producto como tal.
*/
foreach($products as $key=>$product) {
    /*
        La implementación como ves gracias a haber establecido el número
        de venta antes de entrar al loop es totalmente diferente, y eso es
        lo que te ha hecho entrar en un lío durante la implementación. Es
        totalmente normal, la clave es que cuando te atasques lo intentes
        ver desde otro punto de vista ;).

        Ahora, gracias a esto, lo que hago es comprobar que el número
        de venta siga siendo el mismo mientras cargan sus productos.

        En caso de que cambie, pinto la fila de los totales y seguido de
        establezco que ahora el pedido actual es el siguiente y pinto su
        primer producto.
    */
    if ($product['num_venta'] == $current_order) {
        setProductRow($product);
    } else {
        setTotalsRow();
        $current_order = $product['num_venta'];
        setProductRow($product);
    }

    /*
        Finalmente llegamos a este condicional, que es por el que saqué
        el indice del producto en el array de productos, y es que, cuando
        haya llegado al fin al último producto, fuerzo que pinte la fila
        de totales del último pedido, ya que sino se cerraba el loop sin
        pintar la última fila.
    */
    if ($key == count($products) - 1) {
        setTotalsRow();
    }
}
```

## Resultado del script

```
<tr>
    <td>23332</td>
    <td>7</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Compra número: 12</td>
    <td>Total precio: 7</td>
    <td>Total productos: 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>333</td>
    <td>16</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>234</td>
    <td>14</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Compra número: 23</td>
    <td>Total precio: 30</td>
    <td>Total productos: 2</td>
</tr>
```

## Último detalle

En la consulta que haces a la base de datos, pon al final ORDER BY Numeroventa para que luego los datos carguen bien en la tabla, sino tendrás varios totales
de pedidos repetidos.

> "SELECT Id_pedido, Numeroventa, Fecha_pedido, Productos.Descripcion, Pedido.Precio, cantidad, Usuarios.NOMBRE, Total from Pedido JOIN Productos JOIN Usuarios WHERE Pedido.Id_producto=Productos.Id_producto AND Pedido.Id_usuario=Usuarios.Id_usuario ORDER BY Numeroventa"

Comment: hola amigo gracias, una pregunta todo ese codigo lo pongo en ese mismo archivo o me convendría hacerlo en otro?

Comment: Si estás aprendiendo y son ejercicios sueltos es mejor que lo tengas en el mismo archivo, de esa forma no acabarás con 200 mil archivos al finalizar los estudios. Si te ha funcionado todo genial estaría agradecido de que me dieras la respuesta por correcta y una flechita arriba ;)